# A Puzzle with European Flavor

Tags: word

I have

**One** anagram

**Two** Meanings

**Three** primary directions

**Four** numbers

**Five** consonants (not necessarily distinct)

**Six** different multi-letter words- at least (formed by consecutive letters)

**Seven** letters

What is the word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering words with possible relevance to the title, I think the word might be:

> **SWEDISH** - a word relating to [a *European* country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweden).

*One anagram*

> [**Swished**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swish)

*Two Meanings*

> (i) Being from Sweden; (ii) The language spoken in Sweden.

*Three primary directions*

> Among its letters SWEDISH contains the compass points **S** (twice), **W** and **E**.

*Four numbers*

> Among its letters SWEDISH contains ***[e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))*** (Euler's number), and the Roman numerals **D** (500), **I** (1) and **DI** (501).

*Five consonants (not necessarily distinct)*

> **SW**e**D**i**SH** (5 consonants)

*Six different multi-letter words- at least (formed by consecutive letters)*

> The dictionary words **WE**, **WED**, [**DIS**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dis), **DISH**, **IS** and **[SH](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sh)** (an interjection) can be found spelled out consecutively in the letters of SWEDISH.

*Seven letters*

> **SWEDISH** is a seven-letter word!

Answer (score 5):

I think the word might be

> Singled

One anagram

> [Dingles](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dingle)

Two Meanings

> From [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/single), it can mean:
>  1. selected or distinguished from a number or group.
>  2. advanced or scored by a single (baseball)

Three primary directions

> Contains **S**, **N** and **E** (representing the primary directions of south, north and east)

Four numbers

> It contains I, L, D (Roman numerals) and *e* (Euler's number)

Five consonants (not necessarily distinct)

> S, N, G, L, D

Six different multi-letter words- at least (formed by consecutive letters)

> sin, sing, single, in, [ingle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingle), [led](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/led)

Seven letters

> S, I, N, G, L, E, D

Comment: Nice effort. I don't mean to be the party pooper (sorry!), but [ENGILDS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engild) is also an anagram of this word and can be found in MW... I bet you're on the right track with your interpretation of 'numbers' here though. Also, is there a significance of the title to this answer?

Comment: Agree with @Stiv statements. Title is a clue also.

Comment: @hexomino Could it be "SHINGLE"? It shares most of SINGLED properties and ties with the title via anagram

Comment: European Flavor @ArturoVialArqueros?

Comment: @DrD It anagrams to "ENGLISH" :P

Comment: Haha. But you are on the right track kind of.